# Where to store/locate Java data file for the application?

Tags: java, text-files

I use `info.txt` file in my Java program. I know the url of this file in my computer, so I wrote the concrete url in Java code. So when this program runs in another computer, it can't find `info.txt`, because it has different url.

In my netBeans I tried something like this:

```
String classPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
Path mypath = Paths.get(classPath, new String[] { "project_name", "info.txt" });
String myfinalpath = mypath.toString();
```

But I know it isn't correct code. Can someone help?

Comment: You mean _path_. Your code uses the word 8 times. (It's useful info when searching)

Comment: Where is `info.txt` file exist, and what are you trying to achieve. Please clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the info.txt file in the working directory of your program.

when you transfer the project to another computer transfer the whole directory(i mean the .jar file and all the resources it needs in order to function).

also you can make an installer that does what i mentioned earlier